# date format in sms inbox

Tags: android, date, android-fragments

I use this code for date in sms inbox but it shows `01/01/70` wrong date for all sms how do I change correct?

```
public void refreshSmsInbox() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);

    int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
    int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
    int timeMillis = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("date");
    Date date = new Date(timeMillis);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    String dateText = format.format(date);

    if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
    arrayAdapter.clear();
    do {
        String str = smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) +"  "+
                "\n" + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) +"\n"+ dateText+"\n";
        arrayAdapter.add(str);
    } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
    smsInboxCursor.close();
}
```

Comment: some one reply thanks in advance

Comment: The `"date"` column's index is not the date.

Comment: comment the changes

Comment: Look at how you get the values for the address and body.

Answer (score 1):

@Mike M's comment was correct. You're trying to convert the index of the date column to Date format. You're not actually converting the value of the date. Try this:

```
public void refreshSmsInbox() {

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);

    // get the index of the column
    int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
    int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
    int indexDate = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("date");

    if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;

    // loop through the messages in inbox
    do {
        // get the value based on the index of the column
        String address = smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress);
        String body = smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody);
        long date = smsInboxCursor.getLong(indexDate);

        // convert millis value to proper format
        Date dateVal = new Date(date);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        String dateText = format.format(dateVal);

        String str = address + "\n" + body + "\n" + dateText + "\n";
        System.out.println(str);

    } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());

    smsInboxCursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part is wrong:

```
int timeMillis = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("date");
Date date = new Date(timeMillis);
```

`getColumnIndex` returns an index, not the actual value. I think you want this instead, though I haven't tested it myself:

```
int dateIndex = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("date");
long timeMillis = smsInboxCursor.getLong(dateIndex);
Date date = new Date(timeMillis);
```

Comment: unfortunately app is stopped now

Comment: @mgcaguioa's answer is better than mine... it also fixes the fact that you weren't fetching values in the actual loop.

Comment: help sir to fix this where can in put this code it shows cursor index out of bound exception index -1 requested 9